# "Don't hesitate to call us" or "don't hesitate to call us back"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you please tell if there is any difference between *call* and *call back* in the context below?

If you have any other questions, please don't hesitate to **call** us (**back**).

Comment: I would understand _call us back_ to mean _telephone us because we have left you a message_ - see [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call-back-someone).

Comment: I can't see it making any difference whether you include optional preposition ***back*** or not. But including it strongly implies *there has **already** been telephone contact between us regarding the current situation* - and very likely that "earlier contact" is in fact ***the current interaction*** (that's to say, it's likely that the text under consideration here is being spoken over the telephone). I think it would be decidedly odd if I was making an appointment *in person* (at the dentist's, say) and the receptionist included ***back*** even though I'd never phoned them before.

Comment: (So as @Kate says, one possible "explanation" for including ***back*** is that this is a message being left on your answerphone - explaining something to you, and inviting you to ***call back*** for clarification or to change plans if you need to.)

Comment: I think it would sound better to say, "...don't hesitate to call us," without the word "back."  Including "back" would sound more natural in a case where you missed someone's call and so they had to leave a message informing you of your obligation to return their call, i.e., to continue the chain of communication once they handed it off to you.   However, if it's an issue of "don't hesitate to contact us if you have any questions," then they're leaving it up to you whether you need to contact them. As such, "back" (which emphasizes your obligation to return their call) is not as fitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Call me back**" is typically a *request*, not an offer. It is used primarily in two instances (though I'm open to additions to this list):

1. You have tried calling someone and have been unable to reach that person. "Call me back" is the message you would leave either as a voicemail or e-mail/text to indicate that you want a return phone call.
2. You are in the middle of a phone call with someone and that person needs to get off the call, but there is still unfinished business to be discussed. You could ask the person in this instance to "call you back" later or when the person is available.

The only scenario (that I can think of) where the *offer* of "don't hesitate to call us back" would be appropriate would be as follows: you are in a call with someone, and the call is about to end, but you want to tell the other person that if they want to call you again (e.g. to ask more questions that they forgot) they can feel free to do so. In this case, "don't hesitate to call us/me back" works, though it has a strong implication that the call in question will be a "follow-up" - i.e. that it will continue the same discussion. If you want to offer your general availability for a call going forward, you could say "Don't hesitate to call again" or "... to call any time."